# How to use C++ strings in bison

Tags: c++, string, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

For a school project, I'm trying to make a compiler to 6502 using bison/flex.  Not, for text parsing strings are nice -- you'd almost say necessary.  While the bison generated files don't mind `#include<string>` and I'm compiling using g++, whenever I declare a string I get a compile error.

Bison:
http://codebin.org/view/18738431

Lex:
http://codebin.org/view/ef12def2

Makefile:
http://codebin.org/view/b8885243

Comment: Post the *minimal* relevant code here. Don't send us off to another website.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to declare a `std::string`, as defined by the standard header `<string>`, as opposed to the undefined `string` class. If that guess isn't correct, you might want to clarify what compile error you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answered in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@rici wrote:

> Perhaps you meant to declare a `std::string`, as defined by the standard
>   header `<string>`, as opposed to the undefined `string` class. If that
>   guess isn't correct, you might want to clarify what compile error you
>   got.